# How do I access SOAP headers in a spring soap endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-security, spring-ws

Here is my SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:str="http://app.strategyblocks.com/ws/schema/strategyblocks">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="...">
                <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">secret</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <str:updateKpiRequest>
            <str:company_id>1</str:company_id>
            <str:kpi>
                <str:external_id>1134511</str:external_id>
                <str:title>title</str:title>
                <str:description>description</str:description>
            </str:kpi>
        </str:updateKpiRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my Endpoint class:

```
@Endpoint
public class UpdateKpiEndpoint {

    // The namespace of both request and response as declared in the XSD file
    public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://app.strategyblocks.com/ws/schema/strategyblocks";

    // The local name of the expected request.
    public static final String REQUEST_LOCAL_NAME = "updateKpiRequest";

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = REQUEST_LOCAL_NAME, namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @ResponsePayload
    public UpdateKpiResponse processUpdateKpi(@RequestPayload UpdateKpiRequest updateKpiRequest) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            UpdateKpiResponse response = new UpdateKpiResponse();
            response.setCode("FAILURE");
            response.setDescription("Problem with update kpi request");

            return response;
        }

        UpdateKpiResponse response = new UpdateKpiResponse();
        response.setCode("SUCCESS");
        response.setDescription("Kpi has been updated");

        return response;
    }

}
```

At the moment I am passing a `UsernameToken` for authentication in the soap request, that is all working well and I have no problems with it what so ever. What I want to be able to achieve is to retrieve that username from the header in the body of `processUpdateKpi` method in my endpoint class, so that I can use it to find existing data for that user, I have tried to find examples of it being done and so far I have been unsuccessful, is it possible to do it? I have thought about also passing the username in the SOAP body as well, but I want to avoid it.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

someone in the spring forums had a clear explanation on how to read the header from the endpoint class:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109560-Unable-to-read-SoapHeader-in-Endpoint-class

Comment: I didn't know the SoapHeader could be automatically injected as well, thanks for that (-: